# Ask how to delete the last word in Emeditor

Tags: emeditor

I want delete last word after ( | )

example :

```
user1|mail|com|pass
user2|mail|com|psword
user3|mail|com|pasword123
user4|mail|co|@$Haslkf
```

results :

```
user1|mail|com|
user2|mail|com|
user3|mail|com|
user4|mail|com|
```

please dont use other product , I just want emeditor.

Comment: What have you tried so far? [Regular Expressions – EmEditor (Text Editor)](https://www.emeditor.com/text-editor-features/coding/regular-expressions/)

Comment: different macros for emeditor, replace

Comment: -Find: `[^|]+$` -Replace: `NOTHING`

Answer (score 1):

Like what @Toto said, you can use the regex `[^|]+$` to match the passwords. Replace all matches with an empty string. To do this, open Replace (Ctrl-H) and make sure to select the "Regular Expressions" radio button. Enter the regex and click Find Next to show matches. If it works, click Replace All.

[image]

Are all lines in your file like this, separated by `|` pipe separators? If so, you could alternatively switch to Pipe separated mode. You can easily select column 4 and press the delete key to delete the passwords.

[image]